# Page number and auto page break issue in two-sided landscape mode

Tags: tables, page-breaking, fancyhdr, landscape, double-sided

I am making a math worksheet, but I am having issues with page number alignment
and auto page break. Also, I would like to squeeze four tables in one page.
So far, I am unable to fit three tables. How can I fix?

### code

```
\documentclass[12pt, landscape, twoside, openleft]{article}
\usepackage[landscape, width=16cm,height=18.5cm,left=1.5cm,right=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{titling, titlesec}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb, array, calc}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{tabu, colortbl}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[cache=false]{minted}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{bold-extra}

\raggedbottom
\graphicspath{{./figures/}}
\setlength\textwidth{6.5in}

\xpatchcmd{\minted}{\VerbatimEnvironment}{\VerbatimEnvironment\let\itshape\relax}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\minted}{\VerbatimEnvironment}{\VerbatimEnvironment\let\bfseries\relax}{}{}
\usemintedstyle{bw}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\subsectionmark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\raisebox{-0.5cm}{\filcenter\scshape\leftmark}}
\fancyhead[RE,LO]{\raisebox{-0.5cm}{\footnotesize\thepage}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{\fancyhead{}\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}}
\titleformat{\section}[hang]{\filcenter\scshape\normalsize}{}{1pt}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}[hang]{\filcenter\scshape\LARGE}{}{1pt}{}


\begin{document}
%% [table-block] ...
%% -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\footnotesize
\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{qcr}
\ttfamily
\rowcolors{2}{gray!20}{gray!5}
\begin{tabular}{c cr cr cr cr cr cr cr cr cr cr cr cr}
% border
  $n$ & & 0 & & 1 & & 2 & & 3 & & 4 & & 5 & & 6 & & 7 & & 8 & & 9 & & 10 & ...\\ 
  \hline
  1   & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & ...\\ 
  2   & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & ...\\ 
  3   & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & ...\\ 
  4   & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & ...\\ 
  5   & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & ...\\ 
  6   & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & ...\\ 
  7   & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & ...\\
  8   & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & ...\\ 
  9   & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & ...\\ 
  10   & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & ... 
% border
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
%% -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
\vspace{-3ex}
%% [table-block] ...
%% -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\footnotesize
\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{qcr}
\ttfamily
\rowcolors{2}{gray!20}{gray!5}
\begin{tabular}{c cr cr cr cr cr cr cr cr cr cr cr cr}
% border
  $n$ & & 0 & & 1 & & 2 & & 3 & & 4 & & 5 & & 6 & & 7 & & 8 & & 9 & & 10 & ...\\ 
  \hline
  11   & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & ...\\ 
  12   & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & ...\\ 
  13   & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & ...\\ 
  14   & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & ...\\ 
  15   & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & ...\\ 
  16   & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & ...\\ 
  17   & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & ...\\
  18   & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & ...\\ 
  19   & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & ...\\ 
  20   & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & ...
% border
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
%% -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
\vspace{-3ex}
%% [table-block] ...
%% -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\footnotesize
\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{qcr}
\ttfamily
\rowcolors{2}{gray!20}{gray!5}
\begin{tabular}{c cr cr cr cr cr cr cr cr cr cr cr cr}
% border
  $n$ & & 0 & & 1 & & 2 & & 3 & & 4 & & 5 & & 6 & & 7 & & 8 & & 9 & & 10 & ...\\ 
  \hline
  1   & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & ...\\ 
  2   & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & ...\\ 
  3   & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & ...\\ 
  4   & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & ...\\ 
  5   & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & ...\\ 
  6   & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & ...\\ 
  7   & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & ...\\
  8   & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & ...\\ 
  9   & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & ...\\ 
  10   & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & ...
% border
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
%% -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
\end{document}
```

### result

[image]

Comment: You can squeeze in four if you change some settings. See [How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39017/5764) Add `\setcounter{totalnumber}{4}\setcounter{topnumber}{4}\setcounter{bottomnumber}{4}` to your preamble.

Comment: @Werner, It did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a `table` (float) environment when setting a `tabular`. So, if you want 4 tables on one page, just set the `tabular`s one after the other and adjust the page geometry to suit the layout.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{article}

\usepackage[landscape,margin=10mm,headsep=5pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\raggedbottom

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[RE,LO]{\footnotesize\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

\begin{document}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}% Remove paragraph indentation

%% [table-block] ...
%% -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\
\begingroup
\centering
\footnotesize
\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{qcr}%
\ttfamily
\rowcolors{2}{gray!20}{gray!5}%
\begin{tabular}{ c *{12}{c r} }
% border
  $n$ & & 0 & & 1 & & 2 & & 3 & & 4 & & 5 & & 6 & & 7 & & 8 & & 9 & & 10 & \ldots\\ 
  \hline
  1   & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ldots\\ 
  2   & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ldots\\ 
  3   & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ldots\\ 
  4   & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ldots\\ 
  5   & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ldots\\ 
  6   & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ldots\\ 
  7   & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ldots\\
  8   & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ldots\\ 
  9   & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ldots\\ 
  10   & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ldots 
% border
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

\rowcolors{2}{gray!20}{gray!5}%
\begin{tabular}{ c *{12}{c r} }
% border
  $n$ & & 0 & & 1 & & 2 & & 3 & & 4 & & 5 & & 6 & & 7 & & 8 & & 9 & & 10 & \ldots\\ 
  \hline
  11   & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ldots\\ 
  12   & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ldots\\ 
  13   & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ldots\\ 
  14   & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ldots\\ 
  15   & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ldots\\ 
  16   & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ldots\\ 
  17   & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ldots\\
  18   & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ldots\\ 
  19   & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ldots\\ 
  20   & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ldots
% border
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

\rowcolors{2}{gray!20}{gray!5}%
\begin{tabular}{ c *{12}{c r} }
% border
  $n$ & & 0 & & 1 & & 2 & & 3 & & 4 & & 5 & & 6 & & 7 & & 8 & & 9 & & 10 & \ldots\\ 
  \hline
  21   & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ldots\\ 
  22   & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ldots\\ 
  23   & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ldots\\ 
  24   & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ldots\\ 
  25   & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ldots\\ 
  26   & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ldots\\ 
  27   & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ldots\\
  28   & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ldots\\ 
  29   & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ldots\\ 
  30   & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ldots
% border
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

\rowcolors{2}{gray!20}{gray!5}%
\begin{tabular}{ c *{12}{c r} }
% border
  $n$ & & 0 & & 1 & & 2 & & 3 & & 4 & & 5 & & 6 & & 7 & & 8 & & 9 & & 10 & \ldots\\ 
  \hline
  31   & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ldots\\ 
  32   & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ldots\\ 
  33   & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ldots\\ 
  34   & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ldots\\ 
  35   & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ldots\\ 
  36   & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ldots\\ 
  37   & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ldots\\
  38   & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ldots\\ 
  39   & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ldots\\ 
  40   & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ \ \ \ & \ldots
% border
\end{tabular}\par
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

---

Here is a slightly more manageable implementation for your tables using [`tabularx`](//ctan.org/pkg/tabularx):

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{article}

\usepackage[landscape,margin=10mm,headsep=5pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr,tabularx}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\raggedbottom

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[RE,LO]{\footnotesize\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

\newcommand{\onetoten}{%
  \mbox{}\hfill 1\hfill 2\hfill 3\hfill 4\hfill 5\hfill
  6\hfill 7\hfill 8\hfill 9\hfill 10\hfill\mbox{}%
}

\begin{document}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}% Remove paragraph indentation

%% [table-block] ...
%% -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\
\begingroup
\footnotesize
\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{qcr}%
\ttfamily
\rowcolors{2}{gray!20}{gray!5}%
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ c X c }
% border
  $n$ & \onetoten & \ldots \\
  \hline
  1  &           & \ldots \\
  2  &           & \ldots \\
  3  &           & \ldots \\
  4  &           & \ldots \\
  5  &           & \ldots \\
  6  &           & \ldots \\
  7  &           & \ldots \\
  8  &           & \ldots \\
  9  &           & \ldots \\
  10 &           & \ldots
% border
\end{tabularx}

\bigskip

\rowcolors{2}{gray!20}{gray!5}%
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ c X c }
% border
  $n$ & \onetoten & \ldots \\
  \hline
  11 &           & \ldots \\
  12 &           & \ldots \\
  13 &           & \ldots \\
  14 &           & \ldots \\
  15 &           & \ldots \\
  16 &           & \ldots \\
  17 &           & \ldots \\
  18 &           & \ldots \\
  19 &           & \ldots \\
  20 &           & \ldots
% border
\end{tabularx}

\bigskip

\rowcolors{2}{gray!20}{gray!5}%
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ c X c }
% border
  $n$ & \onetoten & \ldots \\
  \hline
  21 &           & \ldots \\
  22 &           & \ldots \\
  23 &           & \ldots \\
  24 &           & \ldots \\
  25 &           & \ldots \\
  26 &           & \ldots \\
  27 &           & \ldots \\
  28 &           & \ldots \\
  29 &           & \ldots \\
  30 &           & \ldots
% border
\end{tabularx}

\bigskip

\rowcolors{2}{gray!20}{gray!5}%
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ c X c }
% border
  $n$ & \onetoten & \ldots \\
  \hline
  31 &           & \ldots \\
  32 &           & \ldots \\
  33 &           & \ldots \\
  34 &           & \ldots \\
  35 &           & \ldots \\
  36 &           & \ldots \\
  37 &           & \ldots \\
  38 &           & \ldots \\
  39 &           & \ldots \\
  40 &           & \ldots
% border
\end{tabularx}
\endgroup

\end{document}
```